# how to get values of multiple keys value at a time in redis?

Tags: redis

how to get multiple keys' values in redis? for example, keys are x, y, and z. they have their own values a, b, and c respectively. I want to get all values at a time for all such keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The native protocol supports the [`MGET`](http://redis.io/commands/mget) method as shown in the documentation:

```
redis> SET key2 "World"
OK
redis> MGET key1 key2 nonexisting
1) "Hello"
2) "World"
3) (nil)
redis>
```

This method allows you to retrieve the values of multiple keys in a single roundtrip to the server. Depending on the actual platform you are using and the client code, the method might be called differently in your client library. For example if you are using .NET and the [ServiceStack.Redis](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis) client you could use the `GetValues` method on the [`IRedisClient`](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis/wiki/IRedisClient):

```
List<string> GetValues(List<string> keys);
```

Comment: sir ,could you tell me how can i apply lrange on both key at a time

Comment: but sir i am using scala/java with playframework  if you  have any idea in these language please tell me..